# Making Post Requests to NodeJS Server Using Postman

Tags: android, json, node.js, post, postman

I am building a movies API with a node-js back-end. I have used postman to create the data to be fetched at the API. The first object works fine, I am able to GET and POST only one object like this:

```
    {
        "title": "The Dictator",
        "genre": "drama, comedy",
        "rating": "7.2",
        "isReleased": "true"
    }
```

When I try to create more than one object in my POST request, the data returned at the end point is garbage, like this:

```
[
    {
       _id: "59b4c78a1157f62f88defdee",
       __v: 0,
       isReleased: true
    }
```

]

The data I am trying to send to the end point resembles this format, json array of objects:

```
[
{
    "title": "The Dictator",
    "genre": "drama, comedy",
    "rating": "7.2",
    "isReleased": "true"
}, 
{
    "title": "The Dictator",
    "genre": "drama, comedy",
    "rating": "7.2",
    "isReleased": "true"
}, 
{
    "title": "The Dictator",
    "genre": "drama, comedy",
    "rating": "7.2",
    "isReleased": "true"
}
]
```

I am using postman to create post and mongodb to save data.                             My code looks like this:

```
var moviesModel = require('./../models/movieModel');

/**
  Get Request For Retrieving All Movies from MongoDB
*/
var getMovies = function(req, res){
   moviesModel.find(function(err, movies_data){
    if (err) {
      console.error(`Collections Empty`);
      res.status(500);
      res.end('A Server Error Has Occurred');
     }
    res.status(200);
    res.send(movies_data);
  });
}

/**
  Post Request For Adding Movie to MongoDB
*/
 var addMovie = function(req, res){
  var m = new moviesModel(req.body);
   m.save(function(err){
    if (err) {
      res.status(500);
      res.end(`Save Operation Failed`);
    } else {
      res.status(201); //movie created
      res.send(m);
    }
  });
}
```

My schema is defined in movieModel.js file. Could someone share with me how to construct this kind of post request with postman or share a link?

I know this question has no programming relevance but it could help me with building APIs to call from my website and android app. Thanks.

Comment: You can send that data to your end point like how you wanted in postman, but the method handling the request to create the data have loop through the array and create data for each array instead. Might be helpful if you are able to provide the code where you create your data

Comment: I have edited the code for that. Pls take a look

Comment: instead of passing the whole req.body straight to the moviesModel, maybe you can check if its an array first (there will be multiple records to be added). If its an array loop through each data and save it on by one?

Comment: Can you share sample code pls?